# Entity framework 5.0 performance

Tags: entity-framework-5

Our application uses code first database based on entity framework 5.0. the model contains about 100 types which map to about 70 tables with a couple of thousand records altogether.
we require to load most of the data at the application startup. for this purpose, we simply call `Dbset<>.Load()` to load all records.

The loading time seemed very long which led us to do some improvements such as pre-generated views, unite types and remove redundancies.

After the above, we used a profiler to check where all the time is wasted, and saw that less than 10% of the loading time is used for SQL and about 70% is used for `Activator.CreateInstance()` (this use is understandable since Entity Framework does not "know" our entity types).

We then tried to use `Include()` to load only required data, however, this multiplied the loading time (from what I read because `.Include()` is good for 1-2 properties), and clearly does not serve our purpose.

Is this the limitation of Entity Framework or there are other ways to improve performance?

Comment: One optimization could be to load with `AsNotracking` if the data is used read-only. But if you want unsurpassably fast materialization of object you shouldn't use a full-fletched ORM but something like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). It's easy to work with, but it requires string literals as queries (potential maintenance problem).

Comment: we require the tacking.  if we load using dapper will the tracking work?  if so seems like black magic.

Comment: No, it won't, but if you want to change objects, why not attach them to a context temporarily? I don't think you'll ever modify all data, so in fact it's a lot of overhead to track them or to load them by EF in the first place.